# Roku device -- "Application Isn't available on this browser" message

Tags: roku, brightscript

I'm new to the roku device. I trying to upload my application in roku device.

- Enabled Developer mode in Roku box.
- Using roku device ip (http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) . I can able to see the Application installer page.
- In 'Application installer page', uploaded my .zip file and installed. I can see the message in green **"Install Success."**

Once the installation completed, My App is try to launch in Roku device. Here I'm getting some error messages like **Application Isn't available on this browser**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USK3n.jpg)

Can someone help me why I'm getting this error ?

note: My browser is up to date.

Thanks

Comment: The was I see it you have successfully launched the App! This is your app screen or am I missing something?

Comment: Are you trying to use one of the sample Roku Applications? or one you've written yourself? If it is the latter, I'd try downloading a sample app and trying that

Comment: which browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Chrome or Firefox for code deployment in Roku. You should be able to deploy the app without this error.